# Refer to aggregate result in Amazon Redshift query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, netezza

In other postgresql DBMSes (e.g., Netezza) I can do something like this without errors:

```
select store_id
      ,sum(sales) as total_sales
      ,count(distinct(txn_id)) as d_txns
      ,total_sales/d_txns as avg_basket
from my_tlog
group by 1
```

I.e., I can use aggregate values within the same SQL query that defined them.

However, when I go to do the same sort of thing on Amazon Redshift, I get the error "Column total_sales does not exist..."  Which it doesn't, that's correct; it's not really a column.  But is there a way to preserve this idiom, rather than restructuring the query?  I ask because there would be a lot of code to change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to repeat the expressions (or use a subquery or CTE):

```
select store_id,
       sum(sales) as total_sales,
       count(distinct txn_id) as d_txns,
       sum(sales)/count(distinct txn_id) as avg_basket
from my_tlog
group by store_id;
```

Most databases do *not* support the re-use of column aliases in the `select`.  The reason is twofold (at least):

- The designers of the database engine do not want to specify the order of processing of expressions in the select.
- There is ambiguity when a column alias is also a valid column in a table in the `from` clause.

Comment: Those are resonable design considerations.  I guess i was hoping for like a #pragma that would throw caution to the wind.  Instead i'll just make the code more mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I loove the construct in netezza. This is compact and the syntax is not ambiguous: any 'dublicate' column names will default to (new) alias in the current query, and if you need to reference the column of the underlying tables, simply put the tablename in front of the column. The above example would become:

```
select store_id
  ,sum(sales) as sales                ---- dublicate name
  ,count(distinct(txn_id)) as d_txns
  ,my_tlog.sales/d_txns as avg_basket --- this illustrates but may not make sense
from my_tlog
group by 1
```

I recently moved away from sql server, and on that database I used a construct like this to avoid repeating the expressions:

```
Select *, total_sales/d_txns as avg_basket
From (
    select store_id
    ,sum(sales) as total_sales
    ,count(distinct(txn_id)) as d_txns
    from my_tlog
    group by 1
)x
```

Most (if not all) databases will support this construct, and have done so for 10 years or more